# Warning: Illegal string offset 'columns' in docs/wp-content/plugins/ut-portfolio/classes/class-ut-portfolio-shortcode.php

Tags: php, warning

Здравствуйте! Не пойму, почему ошибка. На локальном сервере всё отлично работает, никаких ошибок. Как только перенес сайт на внешний сервер, выскакивает такое предупреждение:

```
        static function generate_gallery_script( $gallery_options ) {

        $gutter      = !empty( $gallery_options['gutter'] )      ? 'on' : '';
        $gutter_size = !empty( $gallery_options['gutter_size'] ) ? $gallery_options['gutter_size'] : '1';

        $script = '
        <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        (function($) {

            $(document).ready(function($){

                "use strict";

                var inc = "0";

                function calculate_portfolio_item_width( $container, columns, guttersize, increament ) {

                    var step = increament ? increament : 0.1,
                        size = ( $container[0].getBoundingClientRect().width  - guttersize ) / columns - ( guttersize * ( columns - 1 ) / columns ) - step;

                    if( ( ( size + guttersize ) * columns ) < $container[0].getBoundingClientRect().width ) {

                        inc = 0;                        
                        return size;                        

                    } else {

                        inc = inc + 0.2;
                        return calculate_portfolio_item_width( $container, columns, guttersize, inc );

                    }                    

                }

                var $win = $(window),
                    $container = $("#ut-portfolio-items-' . self::$token . '"),
                    columns = ' . $gallery_options['columns'] . ',  // ЗДЕСЬ ВЫЛАЗИТ ОШИБКА
                    gutter = "' . $gutter . '",
                    gutterwidth = "",
                    guttersize = "' . $gutter_size . '",
                    $sortedItems = "";                

                function ut_call_isotope( update ) {

                    if( $(window).width() > 1024) {
                        columns = ' . $gallery_options['columns'] . '; // ЗДЕСЬ ВЫЛАЗИТ ОШИБКА
                        guttersize = "' . $gutter_size . '";
                    } 

                    if( $(window).width() <= 1024) {
                        columns = 3;
                        guttersize = "' . $gutter_size . '";
                    } 

                    if( $(window).width() <= 767) {
                        columns = 1;
                        guttersize = 1.5;
                    }               

                    if( $(window).width() <= 400 ) {
                        guttersize = 1;
                    }

                    if( gutter === "on" ) {


                        $container.children().width( calculate_portfolio_item_width( $container, columns, ( 20 * guttersize ), false ) ).addClass("show");
                        gutterwidth = 20 * guttersize;

                    } else {

                        $container.children().width( Math.floor( $container.width() / columns ) ).addClass("show");
                        gutterwidth = 0;

                    }

                    /* IsoTope
                    ================================================== */                                    
                    $container.addClass("animated").isotope({

                        itemSelector : ".ut-masonry",
                        animationEngine : "best-available",
                        resizable: false,
                        layoutMode: "fitRows",
                        masonry: { columnWidth: Math.floor( $container[0].getBoundingClientRect().width ) / columns - gutterwidth },
                        itemPositionDataEnabled: true

                    }).isotope("layout");

                    $container.on( "arrangeComplete", function(){

                        // trigger scroll for lazy load
                        $win.trigger("scroll");

                    });

                }

                $(window).utresize(function(){

                    /* update isotope */
                    ut_call_isotope();

                }); 

                $(window).load(function() {

                    /* create isotope */
                    ut_call_isotope();

                    /* store sorted items */
                    $sortedItems = $container.data("isotope").$filteredAtoms;';


                /* additonal call for ajax filter */
                if( $gallery_options['filter_type'] == 'ajax' ) : // ЗДЕСЬ ВЫЛАЗИТ ОШИБКА

                $script .= '

                    /* IsoTope Filtering
                    ================================================== */               
                    $("#ut-portfolio-menu-' . self::$token . ' a").each(function( index ) {

                            var searchforclass = $(this).attr("data-filter");
                            if( !$(searchforclass).length  ) {
                                // hide filter if we do not have any children to filter
                                $(this).hide();
                            }

                    });             

                    $("#ut-portfolio-menu-' . self::$token . ' a").click(function(){

                        var selector = $(this).attr("data-filter");
                        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

                        if ( !$(this).hasClass("selected") ) {
                            $(this).parents("#ut-portfolio-menu-' . self::$token . '").find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
                            $(this).addClass("selected");
                        }          

                        return false;

                    }); ';

                endif;

            $script .= ' });  

            });

        }(jQuery));

        /* ]]> */
        </script>        
        ';

        return ut_compress_java($script);

    }
```

Comment: а вы отображение варнингов ошибок включите на локальном и увидите

Comment: Ну, так или иначе, суть в том, как исправить :)

Comment: ну вам же пишет, что в массиве `$gallery_options` нет  поля `columns`. Ктож его знает, откуда оно приходит в эту функцию, и как заполняется. Сделайте `print_r($gallery_options)` и посмотрите что там есть вообще. ну или вы и так знать должны что и откуда приходит.